# React load file from input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to load an image from a file input but when I `console.log()` the loaded data and then copy and paste it to an empty file, it won't show an image at all. What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function YourComp() {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();
  //---
  const fileLoader = e => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    reader.onload = event => {
      setFile(event.target.result);
      console.log(event.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={e => fileLoader(e)} />
      <img src={file} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your code is working. What do you mean?